# Java swing - application drops frames when mouse is outside the main window

Tags: java, swing

I build a stopwatch using Swing. I put a label on the JFrame and change its text every 10ms using a timer. But the application works fine only when the mouse cursor is over the main form. Once I move the mouse outside, the frame rate slowly drops to 2 FPS - looks like a weird optimization inside Swing.

Printing stuff into System.out, I found that the timer still fires every 10ms, and JLabel gets repainted every 10ms as well - I have no idea where to look for the origin of the issue.

Here's the minimal example, demonstrating the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test main = new Test();
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("test");
        lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 50));

        new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                lbl.setText(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            }
        }).start();

        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main.add(lbl);
        main.pack();
        main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        main.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The label updates smoothly when the mouse cursor is over the window, but once the cursor leaves the window, the label gets updated twice a second.

**Update**

The issue reproduces with JDK 1.8.0_121, but doesn't with 1.7.0_75. Is this a JDK bug? Can I solve it without downgrading to Java 7?

Comment: How can you tell that the app is running at 2 FPS?  Can you add some test to display that?

Comment: I'm running `java version "1.8.0_171"` and I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @markspace I run the code above and I see that the text of the label updates every ~500ms when the mouse cursor is outside the frame. What kind of test can I do? Perhaps this behavior is platform-specific, I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and also using a fairly beefy gaming laptop (excellent for development).  It could be your gui subsystem reducing updates for apps running in the background.

Comment: @markspace I'll try this code on a Mac tomorrow. Anyway, how would you debug this issue?

Comment: Dunno.  If it's not directly related to Java, you'll need to debug other components in your system.  Ask on an Ubuntu forum how to investigate whatever windows manager you are using.

Comment: Can't replicate it on an out-of-date Mac running Java 1.8.0_171_b11